# jQuery .trigger() method in a loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, events, loops

I have this piece of code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#breadNavMain", function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < getActiveSlides().length; i++) {
        $("#studentWrapper").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

The method `getActiveSlides()` will return the slides (as an array) currently activated for my application. What's import is that I am getting the number of slides that are active. For anything over 1 active slide, the loop above does not work. If I have 3 active slides (for example), it will only call the `.trigger()` method once. Within my click handler, if I instead use:

```
$("#studentWrapper").trigger("click");
$("#studentWrapper").trigger("click");
$("#studentWrapper").trigger("click");
```

It will work just fine. The problem is that I don't know how many times I'll need to call the `.trigger()` method so I am unable to do this manually. I wanted to call it inside of a loop like I tried to above. Is there anyway to get `.trigger()` to work inside of a loop?

Comment: Are you sure `getActiveSlides().length` is returning something? Maybe add an `alert(getActiveSlides().length)` before the loop and see what it says.

Comment: Yeah, I made sure that the method was returning a correct number each time by doing a console.log(getActiveSlides().length). It returned the correct number each time for all the different possible combinations of slides that could be active in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should actually work fine, but I am skeptical that something is wrong inside `getActiveSlides` method. May be after first click it is not returning the correct number of active slides. You can take its return value into a variable and then execute your code. Try this.

```
$(document).on("click", "#breadNavMain", function() {
    var activeSlidesLen = getActiveSlides().length;
    for(var i = 0; i < activeSlidesLen; i++) {
        $("#studentWrapper").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Comment: I will give that a try tomorrow once I am back at work :) I made sure that the method was returning a correct number each time by doing a console.log(getActiveSlides().length) so I figured it would work just fine. Will get back to you on this...

Comment: Your suggestion about putting the length into a variable worked. I still don't really understand why `getActiveSlides().length` didn't work for the counter though. I've definitely done things like that before in other programs...